# SF API WSDL - how can I define/see it?

Tags: apex, api, wsdl

Is there a way to see what the SF API wsdl looks like? We want to see what data element are required on the request to SF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Setup > API you will get the link to the different WSDLs available from Salesforce. Refer to this trailhead [API Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_soap) for the API implementation.

[image]